# Java library that uses raw WebSocket transport?

Tags: java, websocket

Is there any java library that uses raw WebSocket transport? I am trying to connect to a SockJS server from a java client. I read that only way to currently do that is by finding a lib that uses raw WebSocket transport.

Any ideas?

Comment: WebSocket is basically the opposite of "raw" transport. Can you not accept a plain TCP connection from SockJS?

Comment: i need to be able to connect to url:port/echo/websocket as i understand it

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [the Jetty WebSocket Client](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) or [Java-WebSocket](http://java-websocket.org/)?

Comment: i havent managed to get import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.ClientUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient; to work, says it does not exist, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Check your project and make sure that the library is actually added correctly. If you're using Maven, just copy and paste the stanza on the home page.

Comment: where do i download the lib? cant seem to find it

Comment: It's almost certainly on Maven Central, since the Maven artifact doesn't need a repository. A better solution is probably to take the time to learn and use Maven.